# Laravel config/app.php not updating

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, configuration-files

in laravel 5 , config/app.php I've set the locale to 'ar'
but while trying to get locale in code via:
 `config('app.locale');`

I still get 'en'.
Seems like config/app.php isn't auto-loaded/updated.

even if config/app.php is empty, executing`config('app');` returns:

```
array:10 [▼
"debug" => true
"url" => "http://localhost"
"timezone" => "UTC"
"locale" => "en"
"fallback_locale" => "en"
"key" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" // changed here
"cipher" => "AES-256-CBC"
"log" => "single"
"providers" => array:31 [▶]
"aliases" => array:36 [▶]]
```

Some hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Cleared the config cache with `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: @ Simon Svensson tnx. just got the answer before you mention it. Tnx

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Seems like configuration settings were cached. use `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 8):

Just a minor additional note to this. If you are running a local server on `localhost:8000` with `php artisan serve` and you make changes to either your `.env` file or in config files, even after clearing the config cache with the steps in the accepted answer, it doesn't update.

You need to stop the local server (control + c in Terminal) and run `php artisan serve` to start it again - then your changes get picked up.

Comment: I would have never considered that. That solved not only this problem, even with other configurations. Thank you so much!